# Why do XML namespace URIs use the http scheme?

Tags: xml, http, namespace, uri

A XML namespace should be a URI, but it can use any URI scheme, including those that are not URLs.

Then why do all widely used XML namespaces use the http scheme (e.g. `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace`), considering that trying to use the URI as an URL by retrieving that document using the HTTP protocol is not guaranteed to do anything useful (and often doesn't)?

I understand the usefulness of DNS domains in namespace names to help guarantee uniqueness. But that doesn't require the http scheme, there could be a separate scheme for that (something like `namespace:w3.org/XML/1998/namespace`). This would avoid the confusion between URIs and URLs, while maintaining domain-based uniqueness.

Comment: I'm guessing the answer is "Tradition!" :/

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Then the real question becomes: “how and why did that tradition start?”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

W3C explains their reasoning for using `http` URIs in the article [*URNs, Namespaces and Registries*](http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/URNsAndRegistries-50). It specifically discusses [XML namespaces](http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/URNsAndRegistries-50#iddiv1128776056) and [a proposed scheme very similar to `namespace` mentioned in the question](http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/URNsAndRegistries-50#iddiv1141937128).

According to the article, the big advantage of using `http` is that retrieving the document pointed to by the URI *can* work and it can provide useful information to both humans and machines.

Comment: A primary highlighted reason listed was, "To benefit from and increase the value of the World Wide Web..."
That is extremely self-serving for the W3C and for the W3C alone.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, I think that it's "because we've always done it that way." If you look at the [Namespace spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/) you'll see that the examples all use HTTP URLs, but do not give a reason.

On the other hand, if you have control over your public-facing web-service, it can be very useful to actually put documentation at the namespace URL. For example, any of the Spring namespaces (eg: http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/) take you to a page that contains the relevant XML schema documents for each version.

Personally, I prefer using namespaces that begin with `urn:x-`, followed by the domain name of whatever company I'm working for. That makes it very clear that this is a *namespace*, and has no other meaning.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for the x- before the company name?

Comment: @PhilPatterson - It denotes an "experimental" namespace: one that doesn't have to be registered with the IANA. See [RFC3406](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3406) for more information.

Comment: As a side note, several years ago I submitted an enhancement request to Sun to register a "java" namespace that could by used for serialized Java classes. Never got a followup email, and a quick search doesn't show it at the bug database.